# Request for member not a structure or union

Tags: objective-c, struct, properties, union

i got a prob when i tried to set webview property on uiviewcontroller.
here the code:

UIWebView:

```
@interface mainView : UIWebView { 
    int currentPage;
}
@property int currentPage;
```

and i synthesize on the implementation

UIViewController

```
(void)loadView {
    webview = [[mainView alloc]init];
    webview.currentPage = 2; // error -> Request for member "currentPage' in something not a structure or union
    self.view=webview;
    [webview release];
}
```

why i am unable to set the currentPage property?

Anyone know the solution so tat i can set currentPage on UIViewController?

Thanks.

Comment: What does your declaration of web view look like?

Comment: my webview declaration on header file is mainView *webview;
. currentPage is belong to mainView class. mainView is subclases of UIWebView.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is `webview` an instance of `mainView` (incidentally, class names should begin with a capital letter, so it should be `MainView`), or is it an instance of `UIWebView`. It looks like you have forgotten to declare `webview` as the correct class type, as the compiler isn't recognising that it has a property called `currentPage`.

Comment: its ok with the type, on the UIViewController .h
here the code in header file -->
mainView *webview;
so webView shd be type of mainView

Comment: For whatever reason, the compiler doesn't recognise the property `currentPage`. Check that you are importing the `mainView` header file into your view controllers implementation file. Without seeing a bit more code, it's going to be hard to identify the cause of the problem.

Comment: yeah u rite, its becoz i dont import mainView.h on the implementation file. i thought that put @class mainView; on the header file is sufficient. its ok now, thanks StuDev,

Comment: Putting the `@class` in the header file (a forward declaration) simply tells the compiler that class `mainView` exists, nothing more. Importing the interface is needed so that the program knows what interfaces are available on the `mainView` class, such as your `currentPage` property. `@class` is used in the header file to tell the compiler to trust that the class exists, without exposing the class's interface to other parts of your program (i.e. classes that import your view controller's header).